# SourceTree - Not sure how to go back to a previous commit

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

So I'm fairly new to version control but managed to setup sourceTree with bitbucket relatively easily.

I also now understanding basic concepts such as commit, push and pull.

I can't however find any documentation (that doesn't involve text commands) on how to revert all my uncommitted changes at once to the last commit (not pushed). I can do it individually for each file but this is taking far too long.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I have never tried SourceTree, but you are looking for command

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

which means reset working tree and index to the state of your latest commit. Looking at some SourceTree screenshorts there are two buttons with same icons that might help you. I guess they have different names in different SourceTree versions. You might want to check what's behind Reset or Discard button. Look to hard reset to the HEAD commit.

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution was exactly as you said. I really appreciate this as I have been really confused with git and most of the explanations I found were far too advanced for me. I tried to up-vote you but haven't got enough reputation of that :) Thanks again!